# confirm() doesn't wait for user to click button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside a classic ASP page I have a `form` where I click on submit to save places I chose in a database and another button to delete the selected places. Practically a two different operation form, and in its related .js file I have the delete button click handler function.

The problem is once I click the delete button javascript's simple yes/no `confirm` message box appears, but it doesn't wait for the user to click yes or no and returns always "undefined" displaying "no" in the console.

I used `preventDefault()` to make the confirm message box wait to be clicked before disappearing but it doesn't solve my issue. Could I have missed something?

```html
<form action="/placeIn" method="post" name="place" class="placeForm">
  <!-- form -->
  <div class="center">
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="placeDelete">Delete</button>
    <input type="submit" id="submittoplace" name="submitplacement" value="Next" />
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#placeDelete').click(function(e) {
    var ids = $(this).closest('form').find('input[name$="placeID"]:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get().join(',');

    if (confirm("Delete?")) {
      console.log("yes");
      $.get('/pages/ACT.asp', {
        act: 'placesDEL',
        id: ids,
        r: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
      }, function(data) {
        if (data != 'OK')
          alert(data);
        else
          location.href = '/place';
      });
    } else
      console.log("no");

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Unable to replicate: http://jsfiddle.net/6tx92Lpg/. Check the console for errors

Comment: _"returns always "undefined""_: are you trying to log `data` outside of the `get` callback somewhere?

Comment: Maybe a bit aside, but `preventDefault()` doesn't have any affect to the behaviour of the confirm box. The said method prevents the default action of the event, if it has a default action. In your case it prevents submitting the form (buttons in a form without a specified type are type of submit by default).

Comment: It works already [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w0qecrho/).

Comment: Could you please provide more detail or a live code snippet. We don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! 
I had just to make function inside confirm like :

```
confirm('Delete?',function(){
  console.log("confirmed");
  $.get('/pages/ACT.asp',{ act:'placesDEL', id: ids, r: Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)}, function(data){       
    if (data!='OK')alert(data);else location.href='/checkout';
  });
});
```

so it worked. I think before it didn't want to trigger really the confirm event so in this way I placed "inside" the confirm call the event to trigger if I press Yes.

Comment: This is not the native behavior of [`window.confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm), most likely you've loaded a library with a custom confirm box.